# I was facing the error when saving the csv data having the 4000 rows and when it goes to the controller then the controller redirect to the dashboard

Tags: redirect, magento, magento2

Magento: I was facing the error when saving the CSV data having the 4000 rows and when it goes to the controller then the controller redirects to the dashboard, **is any facing the same problem at the time of saving the bulk of data ???**

I have tried to maximize the max_input_var from default(1000) to 10000 but the issue still occur
Was Increase the max session size.